# XPage Osgi plug in development

Tags: osgi, xpages, xpages-extlib

**background**
I have designed many tools in the past year or so that is designed to help me program for XPages.  These tools include primarily helper java classes, extended logging (making use of OpenLogger and my own stuff), and a few other things that I personally feel I cannot work without.  It has been discussed with my employer, and we feel that it might be a good idea to start publishing these items to openNTF.  Since these tools are made up of about 3 .nsfs, all designed to use the same java code, key javascript classes, css, and even a custom control or two, I would like to consolidate key items into a plug-in that can be installed at the server and client level.  I want to do this consolidation before I even think about publishing any of the work I've done so far.  It would just be far too much work to maintain, not just for me, but for potential users.  I have not really found any information on how to do such a thing in google searches.  I also have to make sure that I am able to make use of the ExtLib libraries, openNTF Domino API, and the Notes API.

**my questions**

1. How does one best go about designing such plug-ins?  Must a designer
   use eclipse, or is this it possible to do this directly in the Notes
   Designer?
2. How does a designer best go about keeping a server and client up to date while designing and updating the plug-in code?  Is this why GitHub is often used?
3. Where is the best place to get material to get started in this direction?  I sort of feel lost in the woods, knowing I need to head north, but not having a compass for that first step.

Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience, I found that diving into plug-in development is a huge PITA until you get used to it, but it's definitely worth it overall.

As for whether you can use Designer for plugin development: yes, but you will likely eventually want to not do so. I started out by using Designer for this sort of thing for a while, presumably with the same sentiment as you: why bother installing another instance of Eclipse when I'm already sitting in one all day? However, between Designer's age (it's roughly equivalent to, I think, Eclipse 3.4), oddities when it comes to working sets between the "Applications" and "Project Explorer" views, and, in my case, my desire to use a Mac app, I ended up switching.

There are two major starting points: the XSP Starter Kit (http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?name=XSP%20Starter%20Kit) and Niklas Heidloff's video on setting up Eclipse for XPages development (http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=NHEF-8RVB5H). The latter mentions the XPages SDK (http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?name=XPages%20SDK%20for%20Eclipse%20RCP), which is also useful. In my setup, I found the video largely useful, but some aspects either difficult to find (IBM's downloads are shifting sands) or optional (debugging, which will depend on whether or not you're using Eclipse on Windows).

Those resources should generally get you set up. The main thing to worry about when setting up your Eclipse environment will be making sure your Plug-In Execution Environment is properly done. If you're following the SDK setup instructions, that SHOULD get you where you need to be.

The next thing to know about is the way plugins are structured. Each plugin you want to install in Designer or Domino will also be paired with a feature project (a feature can house several plugins), and potentially an update site - the last one is optional if you just want to import the features into an Update Site NSF. That's how I often do my normal plugin development: export the paired feature to a directory and then import the feature into the server's Update Site NSF and then install in Designer from there using Application -> Install. You can also set things up so that you deploy into the server's plugin/feature directories instead of taking the step of installing into an update site if you'd prefer. GitHub doesn't really come into play for this aspect - it's more about sharing/collaborating with your code and also having a remote storage location for your git repositories (which I highly advise).

And as for the "lost in the woods" feeling: yep, you'll have that for a good while. There are lots of moving parts and esoteric concepts to get a hold of all at once. If you mostly follow the above links and then start with some basics from the XSP Starter Kit (which is itself a plugin project that you can pair with a feature) - say, printing text in the Activator class and making an implicit global variable just to make sure it works - that should help get your feet wet.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I think I got it up and running the way I needed.  If not, I will open a new question to deal with the specific question.

Answer (score 2):

It's best done in Eclipse. You can debug your code running on the server from there, as well as run it directly from there. The editors are also more up-to-date. You want:

1. Eclipse for RCP and RAP developers
2. XPages SDK for Eclipse RCP (from OpenNTF)
3. XPages Debug Plugin (from OpenNTF - basically allows you to load the plugins to the Domino server dynamically, rather than exporting to an Update Site all the time)

XSP Starter Kit on OpenNTF is a good starting point for a plugin. There are various references to the library id, which has to be unique for your plugin. Basically, references to org.openntf.xsp.starter need changing to whatever you want to call your plugin. You're also best advised to remove what you don't need. I tend to work in a copy of the Starter, remove stuff, build and if there are errors with required classes (Activator.java obviously will be required and some others), then paste them back in from the Starter.

XPages OpenLog Logger is a good cross-reference, that was built from XPages Starter Kit. It's pretty much stripped down and you'll be able to see what had to be changed. A lot of the elements of the XSP Starter Kit correspond to Java classes you'll probably be familiar with from your XPages Java development.

GitHub etc tend to be used as source control, which is useful for working out what's changed from time to time.

Comment: I'm hoping to deliver a session at ICON UK on plugin development. Nothing's written yet, but if it goes ahead, I'm happy to let you see the slides in advance. Contact me on Twitter, LinkedIn etc

Comment: It's also going to be easier to develop against a Domino server on a the PC or a local VM. You'll need to be restarting HTTP regularly and the Debug Plugin points to your local PC to load the OSGi plugins. So if you're not connected and someone else tries to use the server, I'm not sure what would happen.