# Domino OSGI Update Site Creation

Tags: osgi, xpages

This is a continuation [of a question I asked a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24368293/domino-osgi-dev-and-testing-what-about-a-designer-connection) regarding a designer connection for Domino OSGI dev and testing.

In eclipse, I do have the "debugging plug-in" installed (as mentioned by stwissel), and I am fairy certain that it is configured properly.
[image]

[image]

In a second attempt, I tried to export my plug-in in an update site.
1. import plug-in to feature
2. import feature to update site
3. build update site

I first tried to install using My Widgets in the notes sidebar.  I did not get the thing to run with that so, then went into designer and installed it there directly, also nothing.

**current stand**

1. I built the update site and deployed using an nsf Update Site as a widget.  I use this for openNTF Domino API, the ExtLibs -- it is comfortable and I like it.
   [image]
2. I can verify that the feature is available in the application Management window of designer.

[image]

3 I expect to see those libraries in the xsp.properties page generation tab, but do not.
[image]

**questions**
1. Am I missing something?
2. Must I add some sort of class/code/flag in order to choose this library/plug-in in designer?
3. How can I best verify that the plug in and not just the feature is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your XspLibrary is not a 'global' one you probably won't see the activator run until the first nsf that uses it activates it.

seeing as you can't select it in an nsf this is probably why no nsf is ever activating it

can I ask have you correctly defined the library as an extension of com.ibm.commons.Extensions
as type 
com.ibm.xsp.Library

if you don't define the extension you will not see it in the list of libraries.

also you must make sure you set the plugin settings to export the XspLibrary class (or package of the class) otherwise designer can't use the class

see this article [on the domino designer wiki](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp?documentId=12DDAEA2C840DCF085257728003D0A01%23mobileViewer) for an overview of necessary steps to correctly set up the XspLibrary plugin. the manifest.mf / plugin.xml settings are important.

another thing to double check, is to inspect the actual built plugin jar, using something like 7zip. you can open it up like a zip and have a look to make sure the .class files are actually included in the jar. if your build settings are incorrect it may not include them in the jar properly. also make sure the manifest.mf and plugin.xml are in there properly

**EDIT from Greg**  
[This should be the link for a non-mobile user](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_an_XPages_Library)

Comment: I think that might be it.  I will take a look a that wiki and report back!

Comment: ok good luck hope it works, let us know. these are all steps along the osgi learning curve! I only know them because I've been through the same huh? moments :)

Comment: that link does not seem to be working for me.  Is it an issue with the link, or are my browsers just being stupid?

Comment: probably an issue with the link, I copied it on my mobile. Google 'domino designer XspLibrary extension point' there should be an entry in the first 10 results, a domino designer wiki article by Maire Kehoe 'Creating an XPages Library'

Comment: I hope it is ok with you that I edited the answer to include the non-mobile link.  Thank you, it looks very promising!

Comment: So, yeah.  This is definitely where I went wrong.  I never added an XspLibrary and never set the extension.  It seems like this is going to take me a while to get correct and understand -- I think a book could be written on this subject --  but this is certainly the reason why I could not see it in designer.  I am sure everyone else who answered is correct, but this is my particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you setup the debug plugin, it should create an entry in the workspace directory of the Notes client and Domino server (I think down in the RCP directory). This entry points back to the Eclipse workspace. So you don't need to deploy the plug-in. You also should see a warning when loading Notes ( with rparams -console) or Domino on the console about the debug.

Also what I found: auto deployment via Widget works when the update site sits on a server via http or nrpc. It doesn't when it is specified as file:/// so I run a Apache http on local (I need it for other stuff too, so no big deal for me).

I'll check the exact settings when I get back to my Dev workstation

Answer (score 1):

You can identify if a plugin is installed via Help > About IBM Domino Designer, then clicking on the Plug-in Details button in the dialog.

Help > Support > View Log and View Trace should give more details. Trace is more detailed and allows you to write content, as we do for the OpenNTF Domino API. It may allow you to see how far through the code it's going.

[image]

That first message is in the XspLibrary class, in the constructor, just using a sysout

```
    /**
 * Constructor
 */
public XspLibrary() {
    System.out.println("Loading org.openntf.domino.xsp library");
}
```

Hopefully that should help you see where it's failing.

Comment: I forgot to add in my question that I looked in this file and saw nothing regarding my plug-in.  I saw no errors, etc.  In the Plug-in Activator, I do (attempt to) print out that the plug in is starting or ending, though nothing is shown in designer or on the server.  In the "About" page, I do not see my plug-in listed. I only see the the plug-in listed on the server console with the tell http osgi ss...  Same screenshot as the previous question.

Comment: Check the site.xml points to the correct feature version and that the feature project points to the correct plugin version. It sounds like the feature.xml of the feature is pointing to the wrong version. It should show something like:
<plugin
         id="org.openntf.domino.xsp"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="1.0.0.201406270851"
         unpack="false"/>

Comment: In that scenario, the version in the feature.xml should match the version of the plugin in your update site